# How std::atomic wait operation works?

Tags: c++, c++20

Starting C++20, `std::atomic` has `wait()` and `notify_one()`/`notify_all()` operations. But I didn't get exactly how they are supposed to work. [cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait):

> Performs atomic waiting operations. Behaves as if it repeatedly
> performs the following steps:
>
> - Compare the value representation of this->load(order) with that of old.
>
>   - If those are **equal**, then blocks until **`*this` is notified by notify_one() or notify_all(), or the thread is unblocked spuriously.**
>   - Otherwise, returns.
>
> **These functions are guaranteed to return only if value has changed,
> even if underlying implementation unblocks spuriously.**

I don't exactly get how these 2 parts are related to each other. Does it mean that if the value if **not changed**, then the function does not return even if I use `notify_one()`/`notify_all()` method? meaning that the operation is somehow equal to following pseudocode?

```
while (*this == val) {
    // block thread
}
```

Comment: The thing is, `wait` might exit spuriously, without one triggering `notify_one/all`. The only way to tell that something worthwhile happened is to run a check. That's how `condition_variable` wait works, it accepts a lambda. Since this is atomic, and non-blocking, it accepts only simpler instructions, i.e., if the value changed.

Comment: Yes, the function is equal to your pseudo code. The `wait()` method may not exit spuriously, but the inner block operation may wake up spuriously. But even in that case, `wait()` itself won't exit, because it rechecks the value, first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly it. notify_one/all simply provide the waiting thread a chance to check the value for change. If it remains the same, e.g. because a different thread has set the value back to its original value, the thread will remain blocking.

Note: A valid implementation for this code is to use a global array of mutexes and condition_variables. atomic variables are then mapped to these objects by their pointer via a hash function. That's why you get spurious wakeups. Some atomics share the same condition_variable.

Something like this:

```
std::mutex atomic_mutexes[64];
std::condition_variable atomic_conds[64];

template<class T>
std::size_t index_for_atomic(std::atomic<T>* ptr) noexcept
{ return reinterpret_cast<std::size_t>(ptr) / sizeof(T) % 64; }

void atomic<T>::wait(T value, std::memory_order order)
{
    if(this->load(order) != value)
        return;
    std::size_t index = index_for_atomic(this);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(atomic_mutexes[index]);
    while(this->load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == value)
        atomic_conds[index].wait(lock);
}
template<class T>
void std::atomic_notify_one(std::atomic<T>* ptr)
{
    const std::size_t index = index_for_atomic(ptr);
    /*
     * normally we don't need to hold the mutex to notify
     * but in this case we updated the value without holding
     * the lock. Therefore without the mutex there would be
     * a race condition in wait() between the while-loop condition
     * and the loop body
     */
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(atomic_mutexes[index]);
    /*
     * needs to notify_all because we could have multiple waiters
     * in multiple atomics due to aliasing
     */
    atomic_conds[index].notify_all();
}
```

A real implementation would probably use the OS primitives, for example WaitForAddress on Windows or (at least for int-sized types) futex on Linux.

Comment: If a global array is used, how many elements does the array have?

Comment: @macomphy I'm just showing an example here. A real implementation is free to do whatever it wants. However, if you look libatomic (which is used by GCC for atomics that need a mutex), they also use 64 mutexes and add padding to 64 byte size (cache line size) between them. That uses one 4kiB memory page. In general, you want more than the largest number of simultaneously running threads by a factor of at least 2 to reduce the risk of hash collisions.